# Grid-Based Line Optimisation

Tags: algorithm, optimization, line, trace, polyline

What is the best method to optimize grid-based pointclouds like first image into something similar to the second image?
[image: Grid-Based Closed Pointcloud]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a so called `Simplify` routine to do this. Personally, I would recommend the [R-D-P line simplification algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). There are a number of implementations available as example code or in both open and closed source applications. You might be able to write your own just from the pseduocode on wikipedia. Linked off of the wiki page is [this implementation in javascript](http://karthaus.nl/rdp/js/rdp.js), with an [example of its use](http://karthaus.nl/rdp/).  If you are using any computational geometry libraries or GIS libraries it's almost certainly contained in them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to code this with tracing the edge with 'right hand on the wall' algorithm. This algorithm would produce not only pairs of coordinates, but a connected / closed loop, that can be represented as a string: "URUURUURUURRDDRDDDRDD" ... as in Up, Right, Down, ... and eventually Left, Up, ... etc.

The next thing would be locating edge points. There e.g. must be some edge point in between all Ups and Downs, and between each Left and Right: what pixel/point is furthest away from the line drawn in between (U)RUURUURUUR_RDDRDDDDRD(D)? My candidate is around '_';

Choosing similar technique, one can now draw an imaginary line inbetween (U)RUURUURUUR(_) and check if all the intermediate coordinates are withing 1/2 pixel from that line; and if not, continue subdividing where ever the point is furthest away from the line.